# 8 queen problem. How work this JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, computer-science, chess

It is about 8 queen problem, and I don't get this part of code. Can you explain me?
I don't get how detect collisions on this code? 
What is dp?

```
// Count the number or row collisions
var rowCollisions = function (a) {
  collision = 0;
  for (var i in a) {
    for (var j in a) {
      if (j != i) {
        collision = a[i] == a[j] ? collision+1 : collision;
      }
    }
  }
  return collision;
};

// Count the number of column collisions
var diaCollisions = function (a) {
  collision = 0;
  for (var i in a){
    for (var j in a){
      if (i != j) {
        dp = Math.abs(i-j);
        collision = a[i] == a[j]+dp ? collision+1 : collision;
        collision = a[i] == a[j]-dp ? collision+1 : collision;
      }
    }
  }
  return collision / 2;
};
```

Comment: What is `a` ?  ... It's an array of column positions right?

Comment: ```a``` is array of 8 random number (1-8) which represent position of queen

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at queens that collide diagonally:

```
        [0, 0]
        [1, 1]
        [2, 0]
```

and here are two that do not collide:

```
        [0, 0]
        [1, 2]
```

so if you look at the *difference* between the colliding queens positions ([1,1], [-1, 1]) and the non colling ones ([1, 2]), you can see that quees collide if the difference of x and y is equal (ignoring the sign). We can put that into a formula:

```
  const collide = Math.abs(queen1.x - queen2.x) === queen1.y - queen2.y;
```

Now if you replace `queen1.x` with `i`, `queen2.x` with `j`, and the `.y` coordinates with `a[...]`, you basically have your code.

Comment: Why we have ```j != i```? Whati is used for?

Comment: cause you dont want to compare the queen to itself.